# Should std::reference_wrapper contain the default comparator "<" operator?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, reference-wrapper

The STL uses the "less than" as the default comparator. An STL comparator call on an object wrapped with the reference_wrapper<> [does not compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9139748/1408646), even if the underlying class has the "<" operator defined.

It seems, this is because there is [no implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9139979/1408646) performed on on the *LHS* of the *LHS.operator<(RHS)* when it is a member function. I have verified that [using a free version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717235/1408646) as the comparator works.

However, if the reference_wrapper provided the "<" operator, which calls the "<" on the underlying, the need to use the free function will be obviated.

I made the following addition in the code for the reference_wrapper (taken from VS11 Beta xrefwrap.h), and could use std::map with a class wrapped in my version of the reference_wrapper<> which has the "<" operator defined.

```
    bool operator <(reference_wrapper<_Ty> const rhs) const {
    return this->get() < rhs.get();
}
```

Added later: If I understand correctly, reference_wrapper<> provides copy/assign semantics associated with ptrs needed by many libraries, while hiding the ptr related syntax. This permits the use of reference type syntax, without the overhead of local copies. To compare it with examples using ptrs completely misses ***one*** of the point of the reference_wrappers: *you want to avoid the use of ptr type syntax.*

The way things stand right now, code which directly works on objects breaks when the objects are wrapped in reference_wrappers. Needless to say, "<" being the default comparator, indeed makes it special; in a significant percentage of existing code, objects will define these to obviate the need for special comparators.

Added Later #2:
The history of this feature suggests that avoiding the use of ptr syntax was not the original intent. However, it has been a decade since this was first introduced in boost. With a large number of new programmers "guided" [to avoid ptr based syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149473/1408646) (undoubtedly influenced by ptr free languages), this feature can become increasingly useful if it could work more seamlessly, especially when dealing with legacy code storing objects in STL containers, and value copies all over.

**Added Later #3: Improving Legacy Code with minimal code changes**
Over time thin classes become heavy and the size of the objects in the containers increases. A quick way to improve performance is to avoid the copies, via wrapped objects. This will provide the "C ptr" type performance without the extra copies with minimal changes to the code.

```
std::map<const Object, string> objTable;
// can be rewritten as to avoid object copies using the
// __myOwn::reference_wrapper which contains the '<' operator
std::map<__myOwn::reference_wrapper<const Object>, string> rwTable_myOwn;

// which works with out any non-member free comparator functions
rwTable_myOwn[a]="One"; // Compiles and works

// When using the table with the std::reference_wrapper
std::map<std::reference_wrapper<const Object>, string> rwTable_std;
//the map does not work
rwTable_std[a]="One"; // Fails to compile it needs the custom non-member comparator
```

Comment: @GManNickG  The < is the default comparator in STL, and has a special place in the STL. The question of why stop at the "<" is self-evident. The way things stand now, you could use STL on raw objects with the "<" operator expressing the ordering semantics, but the same code will break once you wrap it.

Comment: No, `reference_wrapper` was not created to act as a replacement for pointers. It's meant as a replacement for references (hence the name).

Comment: Thx for the origins;  @Xeo pointed that out too (see answer below). http://stackoverflow.com/a/9149473/1408646 suggests that there is a style element when it comes to avoiding ptr syntax.

Comment: Question is quite constructive on my mind. You can construct one-liner type `std::set< std::reference_wrapper< T >, std::less< T > >`, but cannot create `std::set< std::deque< std::reference_wrapper< T > >, ??? >` type, despite of there is `bool std::operator < (std::deque< U > const &, std::deque< U > const &);` (and similar operators exists for the most of STL containers) in STL.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235818/type-emulating-a-c-reference-better-than-stdreference-wrapper

Comment: My view is that `reference_wrapper` is **just** a "tag" that hints the function that you want to avoid copying an object. It is above all, a protocol, because the callee has to handle it appropriately. Historically, it was needed in C++98, things would have been different with move semantics from the scratch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080493/semantics-for-wrapped-objects-reference-value-by-default-via-stdmove-stdref

Answer (score 9):

No, it shouldn't. It isn't `reference_wrapper`'s job to do anything but wrap *a reference* as a value.

If you need to compare two `reference_wrapper<T>`'s (which is *not* a reference to `T`), then it's your job to make that work. For the same reason `std::set<T*>` doesn't default to defining comparison as `std::less<T>(*x, *y)`, neither should your case. The wrapper is just a non-null pointer.

Why stop at a single comparison operator or all the comparison operators? Why not overload reference wrapper for *all* of the standard functions? Because it's not worth it when the solution is so easy.