# Tuple wrapper that works with get, tie, and other tuple operations

Tags: c++, iterator, tuples, c++17, stdtuple

I have written a fancy "zip iterator" that already fulfils many roles (can be used in for_each, copy loops, container iterator range constructors etc...).
Under all the template code to work around the pairs/tuples involved, it comes down to the dereference operator of the iterator returning a tuple/pair of references and not a reference to a tuple/pair.

I want my iterator to work with `std::sort`, so I need to be able to do `swap(*iter1, *iter2)` and have the underlying values switched in the original containers being iterated over.

The code and a small demo can be viewed here (it's quite a bit to get through): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fe23b4458d2e692

Although libstdc++'s sort uses `std::iter_swap` which calls `swap`, e.g. libc++'s does not, and it just calls `swap` directly, so I would like a solution involving `swap` as the customization point.

What I have tried (and gotten oooooh so close to working) is instead of returning `std::pair`/`std::tuple` from the `operator*` as I am doing now, is returning a simple wrapper type instead. The intent is to have the wrapper behave as if it were a `std::pair`/`std::tuple`, and allow me to write a `swap` function for it.

It looked like this:

```
template<typename... ValueTypes>
struct TupleWrapper : public PairOrTuple_t<ValueTypes...>
{
    using PairOrTuple_t<ValueTypes...>::operator=;
    template<typename... TupleValueTypes>
    operator PairOrTuple_t<TupleValueTypes...>() const
    {
       return static_cast<PairOrTuple_t<ValueTypes...>>(*this);
    }
};

template<std::size_t Index, typename... ValueTypes>
decltype(auto) get(TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...>& tupleWrapper)
{
    return std::get<Index>(tupleWrapper);
}
template<std::size_t Index, typename... ValueTypes>
decltype(auto) get(TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...>&& tupleWrapper)
{
    return std::get<Index>(std::forward<TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...>>(tupleWrapper));
}
template<typename... ValueTypes,
         std::size_t... Indices>
void swap(TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...> left,
          TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...> right,
          const std::index_sequence<Indices...>&)
{
    (std::swap(std::get<Indices>(left), std::get<Indices>(right)), ...);
}

template<typename... ValueTypes>
void swap(TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...> left,
          TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...> right)
{
    swap(left, right, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ValueTypes)>());
}


namespace std
{
    template<typename... ValueTypes>
    class tuple_size<utility::implementation::TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...>> : public tuple_size<utility::implementation::PairOrTuple_t<ValueTypes...>> {};
    template<std::size_t Index, typename... ValueTypes>
    class tuple_element<Index, utility::implementation::TupleWrapper<ValueTypes...>> : public tuple_element<Index, utility::implementation::PairOrTuple_t<ValueTypes...>> {};
}
```

Full code here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/951cd639d95af130.

Returning this wrapper in `operator*` seems to compile (at least on GCC) but produces garbage.
On Clang's libc++, the `std::tie` fails to compile.

Two questions:

1. How can I get this to compile with libc++ (the magic seems to lie in the conversion operator of TupleWrapper?)
2. Why is the result wrong and what did I do wrong?

I know it's a lot of code, but well, I can't get it any shorter as all the tiny examples of swapping tuple wrappers worked fine for me.

Comment: Sorry but I dont' understand... what code doesn't compiler with clang++? The one that ends with `130`?

Comment: The basic issue is that sort can do things like move elements out of the range and back. It's not required to only use swaps. Things like `auto ele = std::move(*first);` simply doesn't work with your iterator. That's why C++20 has an `iter_move` customization point.

Comment: @max66 Hmm, Here, Clang 5 seems to work fine (and deliver a correct result even for some reason): https://godbolt.org/z/7zc96z. On my Mac though, it doesn't want to compile with the actual code I took this excerpt from. I'll try to figure out the difference

Answer (score 0):

#### 1st problem

One of the issues is that the `ZipIterator` class does not satisfy the requirements of [`RandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator).

- `std::sort` requires [`RandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)s as its parameters
- [`RandomAccessIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)s must be [`BidirectionalIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)s
- [`BidirectionalIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator)s must be [`ForwardIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)s

[`ForwardIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)s have the condition that `::reference` **must be** `value_type&` / `const value_type&`:

> The type `std::iterator_traits<It>::reference` **must be exactly**
>
> - `T&` if `It` satisfies `OutputIterator` (`It` is mutable)
> - `const T&` otherwise (`It` is constant)
>
> (where `T` is the type denoted by `std::iterator_traits<It>::value_type`)

which `ZipIterator` currently doesn't implement.

It works fine with `std::for_each` and similar functions that only require the iterator to satisfy the requirements of [`InputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator) / [`OutputIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/OutputIterator).

> The `reference` type for an input iterator that is not also a `LegacyForwardIterator` does not have to be a reference type: dereferencing an input iterator may return a proxy object or `value_type` itself by value (as in the case of `std::istreambuf_iterator`).

**tl;dr:** `ZipIterator` can be used as an `InputIterator` / `OutputIterator`, but not as a `ForwardIterator`, which `std::sort` requires.

#### 2nd problem

As [@T.C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756719/t-c) pointed out in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137322/tuple-wrapper-that-works-with-get-tie-and-other-tuple-operations#comment111663092_63137322) `std::sort` is allowed to move values out of the container and then later move them back in.

> The type of dereferenced `RandomIt` must meet the requirements of `MoveAssignable` and `MoveConstructible`.

which `ZipIterator` currently can't handle (it never copies / moves the referenced objects), so something like this doesn't work as expected:

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> vector_of_strings{"one", "two", "three", "four"};
std::vector<int> vector_of_ints{1, 2, 3, 4};
    
        
auto first = zipBegin(vector_of_strings, vector_of_ints);
auto second = first + 1; 
    
// swap two values via a temporary
auto temp = std::move(*first);
*first = std::move(*second);
*second = std::move(temp);

// Result:
/*
  two, 2
  two, 2
  three, 3
  four, 4
*/
```

([test on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rW3azfxqq))

#### Result

Unfortunately it is not possible to create an iterator that produces elements on the fly and can by used as a `ForwardIterator` with the current standard (for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46626887/8411406))

- You could of course write your own algorithms that only require `InputIterator`s / `OutputIterator`s (or handle your `ZipIterator` differently)
  For example a simple bubble sort: ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/TM5d65vWE))

```
template<class It>
void bubble_sort(It begin, It end) {
    using std::swap;

    int n = std::distance(begin, end);

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {   
        for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++) {
        if (*(begin+j) > *(begin+j+1)) 
            swap(*(begin+j), *(begin+j+1)); 
        }
    }
}
```

- Or change the `ZipIterator` class to satisfy `RandomAccessIterator`.
  I unfortunately can't think of a way that would be possible without putting the tuples into a dynamically allocated structure like an array (which you're probably trying to avoid)