# Mutable reference member type

Tags: c++11, reference, mutable

I have a functor class that has a member buffer.
Due to the semantics, it makes sense that this buffer is mutable.
(it is, for example an `std::vector` that is used for `.reserve` and `.capacity` only)

```
struct F{
   mutable std::vector<double> buffer_;
   double operator(double const&) const{... reuse buffer_ ...;}
};
```

Used as `F f; for(double d = 0; ; ++d) f(d);`

Now, if for some reason I have a buffer available when F is constructed, I would like `buffer_` to be a reference.
The generalized code is

```
template<class Vector = std::vector<double>> // Vector can be also std::vector<double>&&
struct F{
   mutable Vector buffer_; 
   double operator(double const&) const{... reuse buffer_ ...;}
};
```

Which I can use as `F<std::vector<double>> f; for(...) f(d);`.

However I cannot make it work as

```
std::vector<double> existing buffer;
F<std::vector<double>&> f{existing_buffer}; 
for(...) f(d);
```

because `buffer_ cannot be declared as a ‘mutable’ reference`.

(the member would be effectively a forbidden `mutable std::vector<double>& buffer_`.)

**How can I make the code generic when the member is posibly a mutable value but also can be reference?**

---

I could have two specializations of `F` (one for types and one for references), but I am curious if I can have it one single definition.

```
template<class Vector = std::vector<double>>
struct F{
    mutable Vector buffer_;
    template<class... Args>
    double operator()(double const& d) const{...}
};

template<class Vector>
struct F<Vector&>{
    Vector& buffer_;
    template<class... Args>
    double operator()(double const& d) const{...}
};
```

(I think mutable should be ignored for reference types, for generic code.)

Comment: Maybe [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) could serve helping hand? e.g. [\[like this\]](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ruuwj8GLl4dcZD1a)

Comment: @W.F., nice formal workaround. It is unfortunate that `reference_wrapper` doesn't wrap better. (all the member functions using the buffer need to be rewritten not to use the `.`dot operator. (e.g. `v.resize()` doesn't work when `v` is a `std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<double>>`.)

Comment: yup! missed that... :)

Comment: @W.F.. no problem. Your solution works with more modifictions down the road. I got bitten by this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235818/type-emulating-a-c-reference-better-than-stdreference-wrapper . I think it is a defect in the language, until we have the change to do .dot operator overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines, perhaps?

```
struct F {
  mutable std::vector<double> local_buffer_;
  std::vector<double>& buffer_;

  F() : buffer_(local_buffer_) {}
  F(std::vector<double>& existing_buffer) : buffer_(existing_buffer) {}
};
```

Comment: I think the class will be a bit larger than it needs to be but it should work.

Comment: Another downside is that when copy assigned, `buffer_` would need to be rebound to the new object. (when Vector is not a reference is makes sense to think of F as a value type).